# How can I retrieve a list of Azure DevOps Wiki pages to be able to edit them?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm using the .NET client API to access our Azure DevOps server.

How can I retrieve a list of Wiki pages, so I can edit their content and store the changes then?

#### Here's what I got so far:

```cs
using (WikiHttpClient client = new WikiHttpClient(App.ProjectUrl, new VssCredentials()))
{
    using (Stream s = await client.GetPageTextAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RepositoryContext"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WikiPageName"]))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
    {
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I don't seem to be able to find the correct `WikiPageName`, so I need a list of all of the project's Wiki pages to be able to enumerate and retrieve the correct name of the page.

---

#### Edit

Here's the requested screenshot:

[image: Release-Übersicht]

Here's the URL used:

`http://tfs.***.***.loc:8080/tfs/***Collection/******Manager-Plus/_wiki/wikis/******Manager-Plus.wiki?wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster&pagePath=%2FDM%252DRelease%C3%BCbersicht&pageId=6`

And this is the value I'm using:

`<add key="WikiPageName" value="DM-Releaseübersicht"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the wikis metadata with the method `GetAllWikisAsyc`, in the results you will get the `wikiIdentifier` to use in the method `GetPageTestAsync`. but you will need the page path, currently you can't fetch the paths with the API, you should manually check it (is the wiki page title) and put it in the method:

```
var wikis = client.GetAllWikisAsync("Project").Result.
using (Stream S = client.GetPageTextAsync("Project", wikis[0].Id, path: "Test").Result)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
    {
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me. The page name I'm using doesn't seem to find the page. That's why I need to enumerate the Wiki pages to see which page name Azure DevOps believes I should provide.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your page and the code you tried?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I just updated my comment.

Comment: @AxD Please see in my code that you need also to bring the wiki id, did you pass it in your code? because I don't see it

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Your suggestion worked for me. (I'm looking forward for a hopfully upcoming page browsing API function then.) Thanks a lot for your help, @Shayki!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I came across this today. It's a pretty old question but I thought the answer might still be useful for some.
In order to get a list of all the sub pages of a specific wiki page, all you need to do is to pass `recursionLevel` parameter to any of the `GetPage...Async` methods.

The following code, for instance, gets the the most top page with all the children page it has:

```csharp
var page = await client.GetPageAsync(
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RepositoryContext"],
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WikiPageName"],
  path: "/",
  recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.Full);
```

Hope it helps!